# PDO exec not inserting and no error returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this piece of code:

```
self::$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO import_files(file_url, file_status_error, file_date, file_user_id) 
                  VALUES ('file', '0', '2018-02-03 16:00:50', 1)");

self::$id = self::last();
var_dump(self::last());
```

Every time this command is executed the `last` id is incremented but no data is saved do the db. Please advice.

p.s. `self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` is added

```
# Get last inserted row ID #
public static function last()
{
    return self::$pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Comment: What does `self::last()` do?

Comment: What happens if you insert exactly the same data, straight into the database? Maybe there is a unique key or other constraint that makes the input fail.

Comment: Is this function being called in a transaction which you do not commit? Or did you disable autocommit? If you insert but the transaction is rolled back, the auto-increment is not rolled back.

Comment: The problem here was that the query was surrounded in a auto commit, so that's why i don't saw any results.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem caused by a transaction auto commit flag.